# How to make a purchase in visionOS?'purchase(options:)' is unavailable in visionOS

Tags: swift, visionos, visionos-simulator

the code I had fully functional in production is not working for the visionOS, what the heck? I get this error

'purchase(options:)' is unavailable in visionOS: Use @Environment(.purchase) to get a PurchaseAction value to call. If your app uses UIKit, use purchase(confirmIn:options:).

how can I change my code to please visionos demands?

```
    func purchase(_ product: Product) async throws -> Transaction? {
        
        let result = try await product.purchase() //TEMPORARY JAN-23
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let verification):
            // Successful purchase

    
                //Check whether the transaction is verified. If it isn't,
                //this function rethrows the verification error.
                let transaction = try checkVerified(verification)

                //The transaction is verified. Deliver content to the user.
                await updateCustomerProductStatus()
```

UPDATE: I REALIZED i need to do purchase the ios17 way, but they ios16 purchase style cannot coexist with ios17 style!! wth!!

I cannot do this

```
struct PaymentViewVoice: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store
    @Environment(\.purchase) var purchase // For iOS 17 payments
```

error: 'purchase' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer

and I cannot do this

```
struct PaymentViewVoice: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store //for ios6 payments
    @available(iOS 17.0, *)
    @Environment(\.purchase) var purchase // For iOS 17 payments
```

error: Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'

Comment: The error tells you what to use instead. Is your app based on SwiftUI or UIKit? Use one of the two suggestions based on the answer to that question.

Comment: swiftui, I am starting to implement the @Environment(\.purchase) var purchase for ios17, but I am not able to make io16 payment coexist with ios17 style payments, what a freaking mess, I am really close to give 1% of my revenue to the cat revenue

Comment: @available(iOS 17.0, *)
    @Environment(\.purchase) var purchase //for ios17

Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'

so I cannot coexist payments for ios16 and ios17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

visionOS requires SwiftUI code that is only available with iOS 17.0+. Your iOS app supports iOS 16.0+. One solution is to use compiler directives so that the SwiftUI/iOS 17+ code is only built for the visionOS version of the app and the "older", non-SwiftUI, StoreKit APIs are used for the iOS version of the app.

Something like the following:

```swift
struct PaymentViewVoice: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject private var store: Store
#if os(visionOS)
    @Environment(\.purchase) var purchase // For iOS 17 payments
#endif
```

If you have any code that is only for the SwiftUI/iOS 17+/visionOS version, wrap that code in:

```swift
#if os(visionOS)
#endif
```

If you have any code that is only for the iOS version (both iOS 16 or iOS 17), wrap that code in:

```swift
#if os(iOS)
#endif
```

If you have a section where there is code for both, wrap the code in:

```swift
#if os(visionOS)
    // visionOS specific code
#else
    // iOS specific code
#endif
```

One simplified example might be in a button handler:

```swift
Button {
    Task {
        let purchaseResult: Product.PurchaseResult
#if os(visionOS)
        // visionOS specific code
        purchaseResult = try await purchase(product)
#else
        // iOS specific code
        purchaseResult = try await product.purchase() 
#endif
        // Process the purchase result.
        switch purchaseResult {
        }
    } 
} label: {
    Text("Purchase")
}
```

Comment: Note: I do not have an Apple Silicon Mac so I can't actually test this code for visionOS. If anyone has an issue with this code, please let me know so I can update the answer as needed.

Comment: thanks, let me try, I already use #if os for tvos, let's see it compiles

Comment: yes, it was an xcode thing that was pointing me to the wrong path. thanks!!

Comment: so all the purchase code remains the same as storekit2? (updatetransactions etc) i couldn't find anything on wwdc that refers to the new@Environment(\.purchase) var purchase

Comment: This works good! Just don't forget to import StoreKit.

Comment: @swiftyboi why doesn’t it make sense? StoreKit is the framework for working with app purchases.