# Ios16 and ios17 purchases in same code base posible?

Tags: ios17, visionos, storekit2

Has anybody been able to make storekit purchase to work for an ios16 purchase and an ios17 purchase in the same code base?

I have an ios/ipad/mac code base that I am reusing for visionOS, everything works except the storekit in ios17 uses  @Environment.purchase) to make purchases, but ios16 build doesn’t recognize that. Has anybody implemented ios16 and ios17 purchases in the same code base?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a purchase in visionOS?'purchase(options:)' is unavailable in visionOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77864607/how-to-make-a-purchase-in-visionospurchaseoptions-is-unavailable-in-vision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the use case that `#available` is meant to solve.

```
if #available(iOS 17, *) {
    print("This code only runs on iOS 17 and up")
} else {
    print("This code only runs on iOS 16 and lower")
}
```